# Could the International Space Station (ISS) be refurbished to save money?

Tags: mission-design, cost, deorbit

I was reading an old article about deorbiting ISS ([Death Star: The ISS Doesn’t Have a Way to Crash Safely](https://www.popularmechanics.com/space/satellites/a22592926/iss-deorbit-crash-inspector-general-report/)) and wondering if we could refurbish ISS instead of deorbiting it? I thought deorbiting it would be very cheap (almost free) but according to the old article I'm dead wrong. So if we're going to pay good money to deorbit it why not refurbish it? Even hollowing it out and leaving it in a higher orbit may be better. Assuming it is cheaper. Except if the structure (steel casing?) is just no good. So ... opinions aside ... what would be the cost of deorbit vs refurbish?

Comment: Thinking in the same line, even if the entire ISS has become too costly to operate, why not keep some modules and de-orbit the rest? Also, is it not possible to automate it so that permanent human presence is not necessary (just go there to initiate experiments then go back to Earth)?